# DOM manipulation in vanilla JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

How do I access the parent element of a clicked event when there are multiple elements with the same class? I am trying to modify the content of the closest siblings.

The example includes a jQuery version of what it should be doing.

I am using 'document' as the eventlisterner because '.interactive-btn' are dynamically added elements.

https://jsfiddle.net/gb8tr0nu/2/

HTML:

```
<table class="my-table">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Account</th>
      <th>Note</th>
      <th>Time</th>
    </tr>  
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td class="account">account one</td>
      <td class="note">1234567890</td>
      <td class="time">7/10/2018
          <button class="interactive-btn">Button</button>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="account">account two</td>
      <td class="note">abcdefghijklmn</td>
      <td class="time">7/10/2018
          <button class="interactive-btn">Button</button>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

JS:

```
/* Vanilla */
document.addEventListener('click', (event) => {
  if(event.target.className === 'interactive-btn') {
        // get the closest .note content and chagne it.     
  }
});

/* Jquery */
$(document).on('click', '.interactive-btn', function(event) {
    $(this).parent().siblings('.note').text('new text');
});
```

Comment: [event.target.closest('.note').textContent = 'new text'](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/closest)

Comment: event.target.parentElement

Comment: `event.target.className === 'interactive-btn'` could be changed to `event.target.classList.contains('interactive-btn')`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're okay with using a experimental feature, you could use `Element.closest` to find the ancestor `tr` and then just use `document.querySelector` with a CSS selector find the `td` element with `class="note"`.

I also put an uglier (but still working) solution using `Node.parentElement` - this will break if you restructure your HTML!

```js
document.addEventListener('click', (event) => {
  /*if (event.target.className === 'interactive-btn') {
    //looks nice, but experimental - probably shouldn't be used in production code
    var noteEl = event.target.closest('tr').querySelector('td[class=note]');

    noteEl.innerHTML = 'Changed!'
  }
});*/

  if (event.target.className === 'interactive-btn') {
    //a little uglier but works if your HTML structure doesnt change
    var noteEl = event.target.parentElement.parentElement.querySelector('td[class=note]');

    noteEl.innerHTML = 'Changed!'
  }
});
```

```html
<table class="my-table">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Account</th>
      <th>Note</th>
      <th>Time</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td class="account">account one</td>
      <td class="note">1234567890</td>
      <td class="time">7/10/2018
        <button class="interactive-btn">Button</button>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="account">account two</td>
      <td class="note">abcdefghijklmn</td>
      <td class="time">7/10/2018
        <button class="interactive-btn">Button</button>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Never knew about the Element.closest() method, that's cool. I am going to go with this one, it's for a Chrome Extensions app so I doubt browser support is an issue here.